# GraphEdit making edges straight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

When using a GraphEdit to alter a graph, is there a way to make the edges straight from one vertex to another?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
  GraphEdit[
 LayeredGraphPlot[{"C1.4.4" -> "T1.5.7", "1.23" -> "L1.5.4", 
   "P1.4.3" -> "C1.4.4", "P1.4.3" -> "C1.1.4", "P1.1.9" -> "P1.5.2", 
   "P1.1.9" -> "L1.5.3", "P1.5.2" -> "T1.5.7", "L1.5.3" -> "T1.5.7", 
   "L1.5.4" -> "T1.5.7", "P1.5.5" -> "T1.5.7", "L1.4.6" -> "L1.4.7", 
   "L1.4.8" -> "P1.4.20", "L1.4.8" -> "P1.4.19", "L1.5.6" -> "T1.5.7",
    "L1.4.8" -> "P1.4.9", "T1.5.7" -> "C1.5.8", "P1.4.9" -> "C1.4.10",
    "C1.5.8" -> "T1.5.9", "L1.1.15" -> "R1.4.11", 
   "P1.1.5" -> "R1.4.11", "P1.1.26" -> "P1.5.11", 
   "P1.1.26" -> "T1.5.9", "P1.2.14" -> "P1.4.12", 
   "P1.4.13" -> "P1.4.13", "T1.5.9" -> "R1.5.10", 
   "T1.5.9" -> "P1.5.11", "L1.4.14" -> "P1.5.2", 
   "C1.4.18" -> "P1.5.5", "C1.4.18" -> "R1.5.10", 
   "C1.4.18" -> "P1.5.5", "C1.4.18" -> "L1.5.6", "P1.4.5" -> "P1.4.5",
    "C1.4.17" -> "P1.4.20", "R1.5.12" -> "R1.5.11", 
   "D1.20" -> "P1.4.16", "L1.4.8" -> "P1.4.16", 
   "L1.4.14" -> "P1.4.16", "P1.2.11" -> "T1.5.9", 
   "R1.5.12" -> "C1.5.13", "1.5.11" -> "C1.5.13", 
   "P1.5.14" -> "C1.5.15", "T1.5.9" -> "T1.5.17", 
   "P1.5.14" -> "T1.5.17", "C1.5.15" -> "T1.5.17", 
   "P1.2.5" -> "P1.5.19", "P1.1.9" -> "P1.5.19", 
   "P1.1.11" -> "P1.5.19", "P1.1.12" -> "P1.5.19", 
   "T1.5.17" -> "P1.5.19", "P1.5.20" -> "P1.5.20", 
   "L1.5.21" -> "L1.5.23", "R1.5.24" -> "R1.5.27", 
   "L1.1.4" -> "L1.6.1", "L1.6.1" -> "C1.6.2", "R1.6.14" -> "R1.6.14",
    "P1.4.19" -> "P1.6.5", "P1.5.11" -> "P1.6.5", 
   "P1.5.25" -> "P1.6.5", "P1.4.19" -> "P1.6.7", 
   "P1.5.11" -> "P1.6.7", "P1.5.25" -> "P1.6.7", "P1.6.8" -> "P1.6.8",
    "P1.4.20" -> "P1.6.9", "P1.5.11" -> "P1.6.9", 
   "P1.5.25" -> "P1.6.9", "P1.6.10" -> "P1.6.10", 
   "L1.6.11" -> "L1.6.11", "P1.6.12" -> "C1.6.13", 
   "P1.6.6" -> "L1.6.14", "C1.4.4" -> "L1.6.14", 
   "P1.6.6" -> "L1.6.14", "C1.6.13" -> "L1.6.14", 
   "P1.4.9" -> "P1.6.16", "L1.6.14" -> "P1.6.16", 
   "L1.6.17" -> "P1.6.16", "L1.6.17" -> "P1.6.16", 
   "P1.6.16" -> "R1.6.18", "L1.6.14" -> "T1.6.19", 
   "P1.6.16" -> "T1.6.19", "L1.6.14" -> "T1.6.19", 
   "L1.6.1" -> "P1.6.20", "P1.6.6" -> "P1.6.20", 
   "C1.6.2" -> "P1.6.20", "L1.6.1" -> "C1.6.21", 
   "P1.6.20" -> "C1.6.21", "L1.6.1" -> "P1.6.22", 
   "P1.6.22" -> "C1.6.23", "L1.6.1" -> "C1.6.23", 
   "L1.6.1" -> "P1.6.24", "P1.6.9" -> "P1.6.24", 
   "P1.6.24" -> "C1.6.25", "L1.6.1" -> "C1.6.25", 
   "L1.6.1" -> "P1.6.26", "P1.6.26" -> "C1.627", 
   "L1.6.1" -> "C1.6.27", "T1.6.19" -> "P1.6.28", 
   "P1.6.12" -> "P1.6.28", "L1.6.30" -> "T1.6.29", 
   "C1.6.2" -> "L1.6.30", "T1.6.19" -> "L1.6.30", 
   "P1.4.20" -> "L1.6.30", "L1.6.17" -> "L1.6.30", 
   "P1.6.24" -> "L1.6.32", "L1.6.31" -> "L1.6.32", 
   "P1.6.24" -> "L1.6.32", "P1.4.9" -> "L1.6.32", 
   "P1.6.22" -> "L1.6.32", "T1.6.33" -> "C1.6.34", 
   "C1.6.34" -> "C1.6.35", "P1.6.20" -> "C1.6.35", 
   "P1.5.19" -> "P1.6.36", "P1.6.36" -> "P1.6.38", 
   "T1.5.9" -> "P1.6.38", "C1.6.21" -> "P1.6.38", 
   "P1.5.11" -> "P1.6.38", "T1.5.18" -> "P1.6.38", 
   "P1.6.40" -> "P1.6.39", "C1.6.25" -> "P1.6.40", 
   "P1.6.36" -> "P1.6.40", "C1.6.35" -> "P1.6.40", 
   "T1.3.1" -> "P1.6.42", "P1.6.36" -> "P1.6.43", 
   "P1.6.38" -> "P1.6.43", "P1.6.42" -> "P1.6.43", 
   "P1.6.41" -> "P1.6.43", "P1.6.40" -> "P1.6.44", 
   "P1.6.41" -> "P1.6.44", "P1.6.36" -> "P1.6.44", 
   "P1.4.15" -> "P1.6.46", "P1.5.19" -> "P1.6.46", 
   "P1.6.39" -> "P1.6.47", "P1.4.15" -> "P1.6.47", 
   "P1.5.19" -> "P1.6.47", "P1.2.14" -> "P1.6.47", 
   "P1.6.36" -> "P1.6.47", "R1.7.2" -> "R1.7.2", "P1.7.3" -> "P1.7.3",
    "C1.7.4" -> "C1.7.4", "P1.7.5" -> "P1.7.6", "P1.7.7" -> "P1.7.8", 
   "P1.1.17" -> "P1.7.10", "P1.7.10" -> "R1.7.11", 
   "P1.1.17" -> "P1.7.12", "P1.7.10" -> "P1.7.12", 
   "P1.7.12" -> "C1.7.13", "P1.7.10" -> "C1.7.13", 
   "C1.7.13" -> "C1.7.14", "L1.7.15" -> "P1.7.16", 
   "T1.7.17" -> "C1.7.18", "P1.7.7" -> "C.7.18", 
   "C1.7.18" -> "R1.7.19" }, VertexLabeling -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Arrowheads[{{0.008, 0.6}}]}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Automatic]]
```

If I move a vertex, the edge becomes very irregular if it had any curvature in it. I would like to make edges straight without moving all the active points on an edge.

Comment: Thanks R.M., I will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Hi! Next time try to post the minimal possible amount of code that shows the desired (or undesired :) ) behavior

Answer (score 6):

I think you are misunderstanding the function usage.

Try this:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
GraphEdit[{"C1.4.4" -> "T1.5.7" ...}]
```

It will open the edit window, where you can play with different options:

[image]